# How to Dynamically Generate (raw) SQL Queries with Multiple Parameters Using Jinja2 and SQLAlchemy in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 and SQLAlchemy to dynamically generate queries in python, specifically with a postgres db. I'm trying to workout how to render the raw SQL that will be executed by the database.

I'd like to be able to do this for jinja templates generally - so using a regex replace on `:age` or whatever wouldn't be suitable. I also don't want to have to parse `logs` output from the terminal, I'd like the result as a string in my python session which I can then write to a file using `with open(...` if needed.

### Error:

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
    raise exc.CompileError(
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: No literal value renderer is available for literal value "['New York', 'Boston']" with datatype NULL
```

### Expected output from example below

I'd like to see the following output from the above:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND age = 30
AND array_column @> ARRAY['New York', 'Boston']
```

### Jinja template

```
-- query.sql.j2
SELECT * FROM tbl_with_array
WHERE 1 = 1
{% if age %}
AND age = :age
{% endif %}
{% if template_value %}
AND array_column @> :template_value::text[]
{% endif %}
```

### python code

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, ARRAY, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import jinja2

# (replace with your actual credentials and database details)
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg://user:password@localhost/db', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData()

# Setup example data
tbl_with_array = Table('tbl_with_array', metadata,
                      Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                      Column('age', Integer),
                      Column('array_column', ARRAY(String))
                     )

metadata.create_all(engine)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl_with_array.insert(), [
        {'age': 30, 'array_column': ['New York', 'Boston']},
        {'age': 25, 'array_column': ['London', 'Manchester']},
        {'age': 35, 'array_column': ['San Francisco', 'Los Angeles']}
    ])
    conn.commit()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Jinja2 template
template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="."))
template = template_env.get_template('query.sql.j2')
params = {
    'age': 30,
    'template_value': ['New York', 'Boston']
}

# Trying to render the jinja template with the given parameters here.
rendered_query = template.render(age=params.get('age'), template_value=params.get('template_value'))
stmt = text(rendered_query).bindparams(age=params['age'], template_value=params['template_value'])
compiled_stmt = stmt.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
raw_sql_query = str(compiled_stmt)

result = session.execute(stmt)
for row in result:
    print(row)
print(raw_sql_query)
```

### package versions

```
jinja2                   3.1.2        
psycopg                  3.1.13       
sqlalchemy               2.0.23
```

Comment: I developed a very simple template engine in powershell.  I used it to generate SQl with the actuals in a csv file.  I think a similar system could be developed in python.  But even better, there are template engines like pandas in python that can do lots more than my simple tool can.  If you're interested, visit github.com/dcressey/Expand-Csv to see my code.

Comment: cheers @WalterMitty - for this I'm interested in getting the raw SQL from SQLA rather than rolling something new. I'm aware of pandas (it's not really a template engine) and would generally prefer to use psycop for this sort of thing rather than SQLA - but I'm constrained by the project :)